# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple' issue in LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

```py
print(type(trainX), type(trainY),type(testX),type(testY))
```

**Gives output as**

```py
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now after compilation getting below error

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as a picture. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The error message and traceback seems pretty clear to me. You pass `validation_split` as a tuple and the operator `-` does not work with float and tuple. So `1. - validation_split` results in a `TypeError`.

The parameter `validation_split` should be a float between 0 and 1:

> validation_split: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data provided, before shuffling.